# Kotlin Scope Functions not resolved in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

These are my dependencies
dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.20'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}
but somehow whenever I try to use .also{} or .let it doesn't recognize it as a function, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'`

to `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'`

Comment: Could you explain why this works? Scope functions are part of Kotlin standard library, why does the `core-ktx` version matters?